# How can I enable both password and public key authentication with OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, authentication, password, public-key

I would like for sshd to verify the users' public key and then prompt for their password, rather than just one or the other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not presently.  But there are some patches floating around that are supposed to add this.

See https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=983

Answer (score 16):

This is finally available [as of OpenSSH 6.2](http://openssh.com/txt/release-6.2) (released March 2013), using the `AuthenticationMethods` configuration option.

For instance, you may add the following line to `sshd_config` to require both public-key and password authentication:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
```

When logging in, `ssh` and `scp` will first perform public-key authentication, and then prompt for a password:

```
$ ssh user@example.org
Authenticated with partial success.
user@example.org's password:
```

If you have a password on your private key file, you will of course first be prompted for that. Example [using PuTTY](http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/pka-putty.html):

```
Using username "user".
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20131221-user"
Passphrase for key "rsa-key-20131221-user":
Further authentication required
user@example.org's password:
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH in RHEL/CentOS 6.3 now supports this feature, although I can't find it mentioned in the OpenSSH release notes. From the [RHEL release notes](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.3_Release_Notes/authentication_interoperability.html):

> SSH can now be set up to require multiple ways of authentication (whereas previously SSH allowed multiple ways of authentication of which only one was required for a successful login); for example, logging in to an SSH-enabled machine requires both a passphrase and a public key to be entered. The `RequiredAuthentications1` and `RequiredAuthentications2` options can be configured in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to specify authentications that are required for a successful log in. For example:
>
> ```
>    ~]# echo "RequiredAuthentications2 publickey,password" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
> ```
>
> For more information on the aforementioned `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` options, refer to the `sshd_config` man page.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but in a kludgish and limited sort of way. First you only allow public key authentication. Then in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` add a `ForceCommand` that executes a script that will check the password.

The script will break SFTP unless you check that the command is sftp and allow it through without a password.

I've never tried this so somebody may be able to see more issues.